# Adsense not working on homepage, tried everything

Tags: wordpress, adsense

On the website: http://www.shaditayari.pk/ I have placed a 250x250 adsense ad on the footer in column three. The adsense ad shows on every page but not on homepage. Things I have tried to solve this issue:

- Disabled all plugins and switched to default twenty thirteen theme

  `Result was the same still the ad wasn't visible on the homepage but on all other pages`.
- Created a seperate development server and applied the adsense add
  on the same place.

  `Result was the ad was working perfectly fine on all pages on the exact same version of the website but on a differrent location on the same hosting server.`
- Tried clearing cache and cookies

  `Results were the same. I could not view the add on the homepage but on every other page.`
- Viewed the page on Firefox, Chrome and IE.

  `Results were the same. I could not view the add on the homepage but on every other page.`

Comment: Are you running an ad blocker by chance?

Comment: No I am not. Even if i were it should have blocked ads on the whole website. Its just blocking on the front page.

Comment: Try clearing your cache or viewing the site in a private browser window. The ad was in the footer when I visited the home page.